# How do I remove the due date from a Todoist item

Tags: todoist

Using the REST API, I have no issues creating and updating task items in Todoist. However, I can't seem to remove a due date completely from an item.

This works for setting the due date:

```
{"due_date":"2020-01-20"}
```

I have tried the following for removing it with no luck.

```
{"due_string":"null"}
{"due_string":null}
{"due":{"date": null }}
{"due":{"string": null }}
{"due":null}
{"due":"null"}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

`{ due_string: "no due date" }` will do the trick.

For reference: [Todoist API doc -> Update task](https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v2/#update-a-task)

> Also note that to remove the due date of a task completely, you should set the `due_string` parameter to `no date` or `no due date`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Indeed, it's mentioned in https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v2/#update-a-task at the bottom of the section
> Also note that to remove the due date of a task completely, you should set the due_string parameter to no date or no due date.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `{"due": null}`?

According to the API [spec](https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v8/#create-or-update-due-dates) it should work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that one to my list. That works when you're creating the task, but not updating it to remove just the due attribute. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python to generate the request, and depending on how you generate the actual request, you might consider using the `None` keyword.